# While printing characters instead of numbers (C program)

Tags: c, while-loop, printing

I'm trying to print an ascending sequence of numbers like this: `00 01, 00 02, 00 03,..., 00 99, 01 02, ..., 97 99, 98 99`. Unfortunately, the C program is printing characters specials from the ASCII table when in the digit `d` (the last one of them all), it should only reach the number 9. How can I make the cycle not print ASCII characters and only print numbers? I cannot use `printf()`.

```
#include<unistd.h>

void    print_character_comma(char a, char b, char c, char d)
{
    write(1, &a, 1);
    write(1, &b, 1);
    write(1, " ", 1);
    write(1, &c, 1);
    write(1, &d, 1);
    if (!(a == 57 && b == 56 && c == 57 && d == 57))
        write(1, ", ", 2);
}

void    comb(char a, char b, char c, char d)
{   
    while (a <= 57)
    {
        while (b <= 56)
        {
            c = a;
            while (c <= 57)
            {
                d = 1;
                while (d <= 57)
                {
                    print_character_comma(a, b, c, d);
                    d++;
                }
                d = 48;
                c++;
            }
            c = 48;
            b++;
        }
        b = 48;
        a++;
    }
}

void    ft_print_comb2(void)
{
    comb('0', '0', '0', '0');
}

int main()
{
    ft_print_comb2();
}
```

Comment: Use printf instead of write

Comment: Do you mean `d = 48;` (I would prefer `d = '0';`) in the 3rd loop of `comb()`? (instead of `d = 1;`)

Comment: `printf()` comes from `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: In this program I cannot use ````printf```` because the exercise rules do not allow it. How could I fix the error using ````write````?

Comment: If you cannot use printf, you should include that in the question

Comment: @klutt Sorry, I modified the question now.

Comment: Reiterating the comment by @pmg; don't write `57` in your code.  If you mean `'9'`, write `'9'`.  It is much more readable.

Comment: Do you understand why it prints this characters? Do you understand how computers store text and what `write()` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `comb()` you have:

```
d = 1 ;
```

where you intended:

```
d = '1' ;
```

Note that in `comb()` you also explicitly assign `c` and `d` overwriting the parameter passed.  The parameters are therefore unnecessary. Removing them thus:

```
void comb(char a, char b)
{   
    char c, d ;
    ...
}
```

Generates identical results.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I can think of is using one for loop for each maximum digit. For example, for a maximum of 2 digits (00-99):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<9; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<9; j++)
        {
            printf("%d%d\t", i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want grater numbers you only have to add more for loops and add more %d to the printf.